# How to stub function in imported module while integration testing with nodejs and babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, babeljs

What I am trying to do: run a test that hits the rest interface with supertest module and stub some functions that are imported there.

The setup is this:

node.js
[babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire/issues/19) module
sinonjs
mocha

Files:

**app.js**

```
import * as emailService from './services/emailService';

router.get('/sendEmail',function(req,res,next) {
  emailService.send('subject');
});
```

**test.js**

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import app from '../js/app';
import * as emailService from '../js/services/emailService';
import { __RewireAPI__ as emailRewire } from '../js/services/emailService';

it.only('rewiring test', async function() {

 const sendStub = sinon.stub(emailService,'send',function() {
    console.log('stubbed');
  });

  emailRewire.__Rewire__('send',sendStub);

  await supertest(app)
    .get('/sendEmail')
    .expect(200);
});
```

The above does not print "stubbed" in the console as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried several solutions for a problem like this, including rewire and proxyquire, and found that [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) is the only one that really works.

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import * as emailService from '../js/services/emailService';
import mockery from 'mockery';

it.only('rewiring test', async function () {

    const sendStub = sinon.stub(emailService, 'send', function () {
        console.log('stubbed');
    });

    mockery.enable({
        useCleanCache: true,
        warnOnUnregistered: false
    });
    mockery.registerMock('./services/emailService', {
        send: sendStub
    });
    const app = require('../js/app').default;

    await supertest(app)
        .get('/sendEmail')
        .expect(200);

    mockery.deregisterAll();
    mockery.disable();
});
```

Comment: tried it but it's not working. first that sendStub is not a complete mock of the object but also something else must be going on

Comment: Right, you have to pass an object to registerMock that has a property “send”. Updated the code example.

Comment: thank you but still doesn't work. app has an original emailService and I don't know why/how

Comment: Sorry to hear that, then I'm out of ideas